# Where are join practice questions?

Tags: join

Joins are very complicated. I've been trying to fully understand them for years. The only way to do this is practice. I thought [this](https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/sql-joins-exercises.php#SQLEDITOR) was a good website to practice but most of the questions have many answers that return the same results, since the data is limited. Like [this](https://www.w3resource.com/sql-exercises/sql-joins-exercise-16.php) question's answer uses a full outer join. But I get the same result with this query

```
select c.cust_name, c.city, o.ord_no, o.ord_date, o.purch_amt
from orders as o 
join customer as c on o.customer_id=c.customer_id
```

So there's no way I can tell that either both answers are correct, or my answer would produce bad results with different data.

*I'm looking for SQL join practice problems where I'll know if my answers are wrong. SQL version doesn't matter to me.*

Comment: I have to say, reading that question, I'm not sure what they're asking for, which makes it hard to judge if their answer is correct.

Comment: Yeah that's another problem with that site many of the questions are ambiguously worded. hackerrank.com seems good so far.

Comment: Still looking for an answer. hackerrank.com only had 3 easy level questions I could answer the other questions are to difficult.

Comment: Here's another one: https://sqlzoo.net/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/sql/join

https://www.hackerrank.com/domains/sql/advanced-join

As far as I remember, the solution you give is evaluated on different datasets.

Also you can choose which RDBMS to use: DB2, SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle (unfortunately no PostgreSQL).

Comment: Thank you this looks good. Don't know how I overlooked this site. Trying it now.